# Fighting fire with electricity. Plausible?

Tags: safety, fire, electromagnetism

The article ["Fighting fire with volts: How water hoses could be replaced with electric wands"](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-1370616/Fire-fighting-water-hoses-replaced-electric-wands.html) gives exciting news about possible new way of extinguishing fire, researched by [Ludovico Cademartiri, Ph.D.](http://portal.acs.org/portal/acs/corg/content?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=PP_ARTICLEMAIN&node_id=222&content_id=CNBP_026931&use_sec=true&sec_url_var=region1&__uuid=cd081c4c-070d-4082-8632-77176da17080):

> [image]
>
> Scientists connected a 600-watt amplifier to a wizard-style wand and used it to shoot beams of  electricity at a flame more than a foot high.
>
> The fire was snuffed out almost instantly, an American Chemical Society conference heard on Sunday.

But is it really plausible? How it could affect people and electric installation in a burning building?

Comment: Please future proof your question by including the essential parts of the question here. Blockquoting the relevant passages will do just fine.

Comment: I added some citations from the article. Hope you don't mind the edit, egle.

Comment: I couldn't find any related publication by the quoted researched [Ludovico Cademartiri](http://individual.utoronto.ca/cademartiri/cv/ludovico.html), so I assume this is in initial stages of research at best.

Comment: Regarding the mechanism, I found this (Ludovico is listed), which appears to say that a high EM field is of the same magnitude as gravity, and there seems to be some implication in a google scholar search that high-gravity effects diffusion flames by flattening them. ( http://absimage.aps.org/image/MWS_DFD10-2010-000484.pdf )

Comment: Note that the quoted daily mail article seems to be writing a check it cannot cash. This method does not seem to address spontaneous (re-)ignition in a house fire setting.

Comment: does this means we can explode an EMP bomb (Electromagnetic Pulse Bomb) to put out fire?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it's the work of DARPA (so they probably have got it working somehow):

[ACS Press release](http://portal.acs.org/portal/acs/corg/content?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=PP_ARTICLEMAIN&node_id=222&content_id=CNBP_026931&use_sec=true&sec_url_var=region1&__uuid=1fe17a4d-1ad8-41bb-b4bd-9a1f5e03141c)

> “Controlling fires is an enormously
>   difficult challenge,” said
>   Cademartiri, who reported on the
>   research. “Our research has shown that
>   by applying large electric fields we
>   can suppress flames very rapidly.
>   We’re very excited about the results
>   of this relatively unexplored area of
>   research.”

Also reported [here](http://www.geek.com/articles/news/study-finds-you-can-fight-fires-with-electricity-20110330/) and in most of the major newspapers and all over the net.  I can't find a copy of the paper, I'm guessing that it's maybe not on public distribution yet?

So in summary, yes.